# Java Type Wildcarding

Tags: java, generics

(For the purposes of this post, lets set aside java.util.Observable)

I was experimenting around with generics, and then wildcard types. The aim was to create a type-generic observable cache with deltas provided to the observers. Where this starts to go off the rails is I wanted to allow more generic observers to be used than the one specified in the Observable, e.g. `Observer<Object>` or some other common superclass.

I've since concluded that this is overly complex for my use case, but the problem itself continues to bother me since I clearly don't understand how to use type wildcarding properly.

So if we start with a simple observer interface:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    public void notifyChange(ChangeHolder<T> change);
}
```

And the associated ChangeHolder, in a full implementation this would be more complex, providing lists of added / updated / deleted objects, but this is sufficient to demonstrate the issue

```
public interface ChangeHolder<T> {
    T getChange();
}
```

So with the Observer defined, I tried to implement the Observable abstract class:

```
public abstract class Observable<T> {
    private Set<Observer<? super T>> observers = new HashSet<>();

    public void addObserver(Observer<? super T> obs){
        observers.add(obs);
    }

    public void change(ChangeHolder<T> changes){
        for(Observer<? super T> obs : observers){
            obs.notifyChange(changes);
        }
    }
}
```

And with that I could define some object caches, by declaring something like `class TreeCache extends ObservableCache<Tree>`, (From this point on I'll use Tree as an example class to be used as a T, assume it to be a simple POJO extending only from Object) and pass `ChangeHolder<Tree>` objects to `TreeCache.change()`  when necessary. Unfortunately the compiler disagrees:

```
The method notifyChange(ChangeHolder<capture#2-of ? super T>) in the type Observer<capture#2-of ? super T> is not applicable for the arguments (ChangeHolder<T>)
```

Which is where my understanding ends.

Without the ChangeHolder class (if my notifyChange method just took a plain T instead) it works just fine since it's perfectly legal to pass a Tree to Observer.notifyChange(Object).

I inferred that I should be able to do the same with the ChangeHolder - `ChangeHolder<T>` should satisfy `notifyChange(ChangeHolder<? super T>)` in the same way that `T` satisfies `notifyChange(? super T)` but clearly I am  misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no wildcard in the signature `notifyChange(ChangeHolder<T> change)`. Therefore the generic type of the passed argument must **exactly match** the generic type of the `Observer` instance.

`Observer<? super T>` means an `Observer` of some unknown type that is a supertype of `T`. Since the generic type of `obs` may not exactly match the generic type of `changes`, the `notifyChange` method is not applicable.

There are two possible fixes:

1. Change the signature to `notifyChange(ChangeHolder<? extends T> change)` so that the method works for subtypes.
2. Get rid of the wildcards everywhere, so that you have just `<T>` instead.

I prefer solution 1, as it is a good idea for signatures to be as general as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Looking at your suggestion #2 first, unless I'm mistaken getting rid of the wildcards means that the type of my Observer instances would need to exactly match types, so I wouldn't be able to attach an `Observer<Object>` to an `Observable<Tree>`.

Comment: @StrangelyTyped That's true. It has to be 1. in that case. You can also change `change` to `public void change(ChangeHolder<? extends T> changes)`.

Comment: Apologies, new to SO, accidentally submitted comment early, using your suggestion #1 I can't attach an `Observer<Object>` to an `Observable<Tree>` because Object won't satisfy `? extends T`, and using `? super T` yields `notifyChange(ChangeHolder<? super capture#2-of ? super T>) is not applicable for ChangeHolder<T>`

Comment: @StrangelyTyped Ok, give me time to have a think.

Comment: `Object` doesn't have to satisfy `? extends T`. `Tree` has to satisfy `? extends Object` (and it does).

Comment: @paul-boddington wait,  my bad, `? extends T` does work, I'd neglected to adjust my notifyChange implementation in the test harness which needs to be `? extends Object` as well instead of just Object, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that Polymorphism doesn't apply to the generic types used here? (I did have more to say but yet again submitted the comment early accidentally)

Comment: @StrangelyTyped This link is the best you'll find on that question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/3973077